# Convert not-JSON string to JSON

Tags: php, python, json, string

How can I convert a string that describes an object into a JSON string using PHP (or Python)?

e.g: Convert this (NOT a valid JSON string):

```
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }"
```

into this:

```
str = '{ "hello": "world", "places": ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Australia"] }'
```

I would love to avoid using eval() if possible.

Comment: better you create new array and change this array with this function on php to json json_encode

Answer (score 4):

A couple of regex replace operations should do it:

```js
var str = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }";

var json = str.replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":')
              .replace(/'/g, '"');

console.log(json);
```

That is, first replace any instances of one or more word characters that are followed by a colon (`/(\w+):/g`), and then change all single quotes to doubles.

Comment: Hic please help me on PHP or Python

Comment: No, sorry, I don't really do PHP or Python, but I would think both would let you do an equivalent couple of regex-based replacements. If you didn't want JavaScript, why did you tag the question with "JavaScript"?

Answer (score 0):

python3

```py
import re

s = "{ hello: 'world', places: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia'] }"
# ' => "
s = re.sub(r"'", '"', s)  # or s = s.replace("'",'"')
# key: => "key":
s = re.sub(r'(\w+):', '"\g<1>":', s)
print(s)
# { "hello": "world", "places": ["Africa", "America", "Asia", "Australia"] }
```